# How to replace values in python numpy array in multiple dimensions using a mask?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to replace values in a `numpy` array using boolean logic in dimensions `>= 3`.  All the examples I can find are for 1d or 2d arrays such that you can say something like `A[A>.5] = 1`.
That I understand.  I want to do something like this:

`A[B==0,2 > 128] = 0`.  Basically, I have a 2D map (`B`) whose dimensions are the same as the first two in `A`.  So everywhere `B == 0` and the third channel (like B of RGB in an image) is greater than 128 I want to set the 3rd channel to zero, leaving the other two channels.

I can do this in a loop or doing a for value in array loop, but I was hoping someone could tell me if I could do it in a similar manner to `A[A>.5] = 1`.

I have tried `A[B==0,2 > 128] = 0`, but I get `IndexError: in the future, 0-d boolean arrays will be interpreted as a valid boolean index` and I can't really think of any other ways to write this.

One thing I forgot to mention - currently I can do `A[B==0,2] = 0`.  I am just trying how to fit that extra conditional in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A[(B == 0)*(A[..., 2] > 128), 2] = 0
```

Explanation:

- `B == 0` and `A[..., 2] > 128` are the same dimensions, where `[..., 2]` specifies that slicing occurs in all axes in all dimensions until the last dimension, where only the axis indexed by `2` is sliced. This product of the two is `False` for any condition which doesn't fulfils your requirements.
- `2` is the third axis of `A` on the last dimension.